# JavaFX 11 Error intializing QuantumRenderer when running custom JRE image on Windows

Tags: windows, maven, javafx, jlink

I have built my app with JavaFX 11 and now I need to distribute it. I have chosen to distribute it in two ways: cross-platform fat-jar (I know, I know, it is discouraged, but that is not the point) and platform specific image created with jlink.

I am building on Linux Mint 20.1. I am using Maven and creating runtime image with `javafx-maven-plugin`. I have JDKs for both platforms on my Linux machine and pointed to the corresponding `jmods` folder in `pom.xml`.

The built fat-jar works on both Linux and Windows where both have installed the latest Java SDK (11.0.12).

The image for Linux also works without problems.

However, the image for Windows does not run and the output of `-Dprism.verbose=true` is this:

```
B:\Data\sjsm\releases\1.0\sjsm-1.0-win\bin>sjsm-1.0-launcher.bat                                                        Prism pipeline init order: d3d sw
Using Double Precision Marlin Rasterizer
Using dirty region optimizations
Not using texture mask for primitives
Not forcing power of 2 sizes for textures
Using hardware CLAMP_TO_ZERO mode
Opting in for HiDPI pixel scaling
Prism pipeline name = com.sun.prism.d3d.D3DPipeline
GraphicsPipeline.createPipeline failed for com.sun.prism.d3d.D3DPipeline
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.prism.d3d.D3DPipeline
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.prism.GraphicsPipeline.createPipeline(Unknown Source)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.init(Unknown Source)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
*** Fallback to Prism SW pipeline
Prism pipeline name = com.sun.prism.sw.SWPipeline
GraphicsPipeline.createPipeline failed for com.sun.prism.sw.SWPipeline
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no prism_sw in java.library.path: [B:\Data\sjsm\releases\1.0\sjsm-1.0-win\bin, C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin, C:\WINDOWS\system32, C:\WINDOWS, C:\Program Files\Eclipse Foundation\jdk-11.0.12.7-hotspot\bin, C:\WINDOWS\system32, C:\WINDOWS, C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem, C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\, C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\, C:\Program Files\dotnet\, B:\xampp\php, B:\MinGW\bin, C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\, B:\Git\cmd, B:\Matlab R2020a\bin, B:\Microsoft VS Code\bin, C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps, B:\xampp\php, ., .]
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.utils.NativeLibLoader.loadLibraryInternal(Unknown Source)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.utils.NativeLibLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.prism.sw.SWPipeline.lambda$static$0(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.prism.sw.SWPipeline.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.prism.GraphicsPipeline.createPipeline(Unknown Source)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.init(Unknown Source)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Graphics Device initialization failed for :  d3d, sw
Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer.getInstance(Unknown Source)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.init(Unknown Source)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.getToolkit(Unknown Source)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(Unknown Source)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(Unknown Source)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.startToolkit(Unknown Source)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(Unknown Source)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.init(Unknown Source)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
... 1 more
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: No toolkit found
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.getToolkit(Unknown Source)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(Unknown Source)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(Unknown Source)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.startToolkit(Unknown Source)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(Unknown Source)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I got the same response when I tried to run the project from source on Windows. (I copied the project to Windows, installed maven, and it would not even run with `javafx:run`, let alone jlink with `javafx:jlink`)

I have tried many links on Google and none of them works, People either have something missing in their installation (I have everything installed at least as far as I have found) or the issue pops up in a different situation (when packaging a fat-jar for example, or running their application from IDE).

What I have not tried so far is creating the image by hand from command line, since I have read many times that it is discourage compared to using a build tool like Maven.

What can I try next?

Comment: (Aside: inline formatting `like so` only needs single backticks. Triple backticks are for block formatting).

Comment: i could be wrong but I think the javafx natives for Windows (bunch of dll files) are missing from the library path

Comment: In a link I found on the internet someone had the same error and their problem was they were missing MS API dlls. I have checked that and all of them are present. However I did not find a list of all dlls that should be present so I cannot check that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to solve this. The javafx-maven-plugin expects in `<jModsPath>` a colon separated list of paths to ALL jmods, not just the standard oridinary JDK. It pulls what's missing out of maven repository I think but ignores all platform clasifiers.

Answer (score 0):

> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no prism_sw in java.library.path

Means you're definitely missing some dlls from your library path, although this could only be a part of the problem.

When you download javafx sdk for windows from [this link](https://gluonhq.com/products/javafx/), you get a zip with the following structure:

[image]

The bin folder contains all the natives you need to run JavaFx (on windows, or the platform you downloaded the sdk for)

Note that you don't always need all the natives, jfxwebkit.dll for example is only needed when you work with javafx-web.

You need to extract them somewhere and add the folder you extracted them in to the library path when you run the java program

```
java "-Djava.library.path=path_to_natives" -classpath "your_classpath" <Your main class>
```

Comment: I am using JavaFX 11 which cannot be downloaded from gluon for free (or at least I did not find a way). Further more I am using Maven so I would expect it to download all necessary dependencies for JavaFX